# how to display the letter ൺ using keyboard in a text editor

Tags: ms-word, keyboard, typesetting

I am having trouble in displaying this line ൺ while using google keyboard

I found out that the encodings corresponding of ൺ is

[image]

```
HTML Entity:    
&#3450;
&#xD7A;
UTF-8 Encoding: 0xE0 0xB5 0xBA
UTF-16 Encoding:    0x0D7A
UTF-32 Encoding:    0x00000D7A
```

How can i display this letter alone in a text editor using keyboard combinations

Is there any way in which i can map this encoding to a key combination in text editors such as gedit or in word processing systems like ms-word so that i can invoke those keys while pressing a key combination

Please excuse me if this is a stupid question ..Only because of hours of labour i am posting it here as i couldnt find a decent method on how to do this

I know you can copy paste that character alone

But while serious texting scenerious that seems to be irritating

Any help would be highly appreciable

Comment: You can see this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/174874) from superuser.  You can open `gedit`, then `Ctrl + Shift + U` to enable utf entry, and type in `D7A`, this `ൺ` character will appear

Comment: You can add any character to `gedit` using `Ctrl + Shift + U` then typing in the hexadecimal value of that character

Comment: @PatioFurnitureIsCool That worked fine..Thanks a lot ..Also to type unicode after typing you should selet it and press ALT + X ..that googleing after your help with that help ...got me to do that ...thanks